# Selecting only the very last set of rows matching the criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

Considering following data

```
test1=# select * from sample order by created_at DESC;
 id | status | service |     created_at
----+--------+---------+---------------------
  8 | OK     |       1 | 2015-09-16 11:54:00
  7 | OK     |       1 | 2015-09-16 11:53:00
  6 | FAIL   |       1 | 2015-09-16 11:52:00
  5 | OK     |       1 | 2015-09-16 11:51:00
```

How can I select only the rows with ID 7 and 8. Using window functions I can get row numbers partitioned over status, but so far did not figure out the way how to limit the results only to the last rows identifying 'successful period' for given `service`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the time of the most recent `status = 'FAIL'` for each `service`, then select those records of the same `service` that are more recent:

```
SELECT *
FROM sample
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT service, max(created_at) AS last_fail
  FROM sample
  WHERE status = 'FAIL'
  GROUP BY service) f USING (service)
WHERE created_at > last_fail
   OR last_fail IS NULL;     -- also show services without ever failing
```

This assumes there are only two status codes. If there are more, add a `status = 'OK'` filter to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Great. Was so focused on analytical functions that completely ignored the simpler way :)

Answer (score 1):

The most simple approach would be this:

```
   SELECT *
   FROM sample AS s
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT service, max(id)
              FROM sample
              WHERE status = 'FAIL'
              GROUP BY service) AS q
   ON s.id > q.id 
      AND s.service = q.service
```